# Creating a 2d fence diagram

Tags: plot, 2d

I'm a student studying in Geophysics. and studying python now.

I have a problem with how to express my data.

The data I have is inversed and expressed as an image file or dat file. what I want is to show each data on the map according to the coordinates.
(like this "https://images.app.goo.gl/8ttayaPvvjBBNnKU8")

I think the simplest way is to give coordinates to both ends of the image and plot it in the z-axis direction. (I already know about coordinate both sides)

But I don't know how to start. Please, a bit of small advice?